# How to assign bool value to a variable and pass assigned variable to a if statement in Python

Tags: python

```py
RandomList=["apple",69]

element=input("enter a element")
bool x = element.isnumeric()
if(True == x)
    (print(RandomList))
```

I want to print `RandomList` if the user passes a numeric value to `element`.

But I'm getting the below error on line `bool x = element.isnumeric()`

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You seem to be specifying that x is a boolean, like you would in other programming languages. I think that's your syntax error, but you should probably edit your post and include the whole traceback. Try `x = element.isnumeric()` and the if statement should be `if x:` Finally, there's no need for the parentheses around the print statement.

Comment: You can declare the static variable type in Python using **var_name: type** if you don't want your variable to be dynamic variables..

Comment: How do you think `if ... == True:` works? What’s up with all the parentheses in your code, and the `CamelCase` variable name? This isn’t Java, eh.

Comment: You can't just make up syntax and expect it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `invalid syntax` because of the use of "bool." In, Python, you do not need to specify the type on a variable. A valid input would look like: `u"22364"`. This will return `True`. If the user inputs something like `u"hello22364"`, it will return `False`.

```
RandomList=["apple",69]

element=input("enter a element")
x = element.isnumeric()
if x:
    print(RandomList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `x: bool = element.isnumeric()` and `if x: print(RandomList)` statement instead.

```
RandomList = ["apple",69]

element = input("Enter a element: ")
x: bool = element.isnumeric()
if x: 
    print(RandomList)
```